# Triggering action at sheet opening

Tags: qliksense

I create a menu in QlikSense thanks to the "Sheet Navigation & Action" extension.
One of my button triggers a selection before redirects to a sheet. My issue is if a user directly opens this sheet without clicking my button, the selection is not trigger.

So, is there a way to trigger a selection at the opening of a sheet in QlikSense like in QlikView?

If no, is there a good extension in Qlik Branch to do it? Does [this one (SheetEvents)](http://branch.qlik.com/#!/project/58e20b0e86f54ab8e8f21512) is reliable?

Thanks for yours answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the SheetEvents extension. Here's my feedback.

To use the extension, you must add a blank object to your sheets which is pretty annoying

[image]

But the extension proposes a large choice of actions

[image]